# Adding Multiple Objects to North part of Java Window

Tags: java, formatting, window

I want to display multiple objects in the north part of a java window. Here is my code:

```
//Create and add Win and Loss counters.

int winCount=0;
winCounter=new Label("Wins: " +  winCount);
this.add(winCounter,"North");

int lossCount=0;    
lossCounter=new Label("Losses: " + lossCount);
this.add(lossCounter,"North");
```

The problem with this code is that it only displays the loss counter. Any help on how to display multiple objects into the North field of a java window?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nest `winCounter` and `lossCounter` inside another container that provides whatever layout you want for them. Then add that container as the North component.

Comment: How would I go about creating container like this? I'm new, so I'm still getting a hang of the concepts of Java.

Comment: @JackDavis You could perhaps create a Panel with a FlowLayout and add `winCounter` and `lossCounter` to that, then add the Panel as the North component. (This would be if you are using AWT. Other UI frameworks, like Swing or SWT, would have analogous containers.)

Comment: In Swing you might use a `JPanel` or perhaps a `JToolBar`.  You might use a `FlowLayout`, `GridLayout` or `BoxLayout` in the `JPanel` to support multiple components.  A `JToolBar` already has a layout that accepts multiple components.

Comment: Do you think you could show the code of the JPanel that would contain two objects?

Comment: Ok, so the program I have which I got from a tutorial does hold the north contents in a Panel with just one button in it. When I add the counter to it, the applet doesn't initialize. Help?

Comment: @JackDavis - What does "the applet doesn't initialize" mean? Do you get an exception? A blank screen? Something else? If an exception, please post the code and the stack trace. It would be better to edit your original question rather than trying to post all that in a comment.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working, but I meant it had a black screen saying the applet not initializing.